# For which $k$ can $(x-1)^{k} - (x+1)^{k}$ be divided by $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

> Consider 
>   $$
> f_{n}(x) = (x-1)^{n} - (x+1)^{n}\,. 
> $$
>   For which $n$ can it be divided by $x$?

Explicitly I found that for $k = 1, 3$ $f_{n}(x)$ can not be divided by $x$, while for $n = 2$ It can.

Next, I used the formula

$$
a^{n} - b^{n} = (a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b + \dots + ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}),
$$

but I don't see the way to show something from it explicitly.

Comment: use the fact that $a^{2n}-b^{2n}= (a^n-b^n)(a^n+b^n)$

Comment: @ALG : it seems that this expansion shows that for each $n = 2m$ the expression can be divided by $n$ because of the identity $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1} = (a+b)\dots$. But it doesn't tell in general what is the situation for $n = 2m+1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p(x)=x^k$. Since $f(x)=p(x-1)-p(x+1)$ is divisible by $x$ we see that $x=0$ is zero of $f(x)$, so $p(-1)=p(1)$, so $$(-1)^k = 1^k$$ and that is only if $k$ is even.

Comment: Thank you John!

Answer (score 3):

$f_k(x)=(x-1)^k-(x+1)^k$ can be divided by $x$  when $f_k(0)=0$.  So, but if $f_k(0)=0$, then $(-1)^k=1^k$, and so $k$ is even.  The converse is similar.  Hence $f_k(x)$ is divisible by $x$ if and only if $k$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

For $x$ to divide $f_n(x)$, we should have $f_n(0)=0$. This means $(-1)^n-(1)^n=(-1)^n-1=0$. This can happen only when $n$ is even.

Comment: Everything here is *if and only if*.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$f_n(x)\equiv (-1)^n-1 \pmod x$$

Answer (score -1):

I would say that for all even $n$. Observe that, irrespective of the value of $n$, $(x+1)^n=x^n+....+1.$ On the other hand, $(x-1)^n=x^n-....+(-1)^n.$ The last term in this polynomial will be $+1$ for even $n$, and, thus, the difference, $ (x-1)^n-(x+1)^n$ is just a polynomial of degree $n-1$ without a constant term which can always be divided by $x.$ Again, this is true only for even $n.$

Comment: But for $n = 3$ the value $f_{3}(x) = -6x^{2} - 2$, which means that it can not be divided by $x$.

Comment: Note that the constant term in the expansion of $(x-1)^n$ is $(-1)^n$, not $+1$.